Microsoft Graph SDK with pageIterator
I'm facing a wall here, as the solution proposed by Microsoft doesn't work as expected and is not even building. Here is my issue: I want to return all the users from a specific group with expanded information (for the manager). I'm trying to handle it with PageIterator as stated in the documentation, but I'm facing the below error:

On the return true, I receive the error Cannot implicitly convert type "bool" to "System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool>
But the code looks exactly as described in the documentation: here
Am I missing something?
Thank you all for your help!

Add await before _graphClient.Groups[groupId].Members


It does solve the problem indeed, thank you!! I missed that point :(
